# Different between form.submit with method

Tags: javascript, forms, struts2, submit

There is some code I am working on:

**`verify_scan_image_main.jsp`:**

```
......

<s:form id="scanImageReportFrom" action="" method="post">
    ......
    <tr>

        <td align="left" width="12%">
            <s:submit type="button" label="Find" onclick="return goFind();" 
                    method="verifyScanImage" style="width:60px" theme="simple" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</s:form>

<script language="JavaScript">
function goFind()
{
    ......

    scanImageReportFrom.action = 'scanimagereport/verifyScanImage.action';
    scanImageReportFrom.submit();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<struts>
    ......

    <package name="scanimagereport" extends="struts-default">
        ......

        <action name="verifyScanImage"
               class="hk.net.scanimagereport.action.VerifyScanImageAction" 
               method="verifyScanImage">
            <result name="success">/verify_scan_image_main.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/verify_scan_image_main.jsp</result>
        </action>       
    </package>
</struts>
```

In the above code, if I change the `goFind()` function as follows, the result is not same.  I don't understand why.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function goFind()
  {
     ......

     //scanImageReportFrom.action = 'scanimagereport/verifyScanImage.action';
     //scanImageReportFrom.submit();
     //return false;
     return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I should do as follows.

The result will be same. 

function goFind() 
{ 
    ...... 
    scanImageReportFrom.action = 'scanimagereport/verifyScanImage.action'; 
    //scanImageReportFrom.submit(); 
    //return false; 
    return true; 
}

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `onsubmit` event instead on click.

Otherwise, it will submit to the action `""` as per your action attribute with method `verifyScanImage()`.